# How to parse json response using JQ

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parsing, jq, amazon-elb

I have a requirement to grab the target group arn the base listener is on so that i can store that in a variable and perform the health check for that target group. Here is what i am doing :-

```html
aws elbv2 --region us-east-1 describe-rules '--listener-arn=************'
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Priority": "1", 
            "Conditions": [
                {
                    "Field": "host-header", 
                    "HostHeaderConfig": {
                        "Values": [
                            "****"
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "Values": [
                        "****"
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "RuleArn": "xyz", 
            "IsDefault": false, 
            "Actions": [
                {
                    "TargetGroupArn": "****", 
                    "Type": "forward"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Priority": "default", 
            "Conditions": [], 
            "RuleArn": "abc", 
            "IsDefault": true, 
            "Actions": [
                {
                    "TargetGroupArn": "***", 
                    "Type": "forward", 
                    "Order": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i have to extract the value of TargetGroupArn for "RuleArn": "xyz" which means i need to get that targetgroup arn so that i can use that in my next command something like  :-

```html
aws elbv2 --region us-east-1 describe-target-health --target-group-arn=***
```

Once i run this i will get a json output for healthy targets which i need to further query upon with some if and else condition. How do i get the jq to parse the initial json to grab the target group arn as mentioned above so that i can use that for my future commands. Please note that that value of the TargetGroupArn for "RuleArn": "xyz" is not constant in our case as they keep switching from one target group to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this two ways. The first is to use AWS CLI inbuilt JMES path via the --query param.

```
aws elbv2 --region us-west-2 describe-rules \
    '--listener-arn=************' \
    --query "Rules[?RuleArn == 'xyz'].Actions[0].TargetGroupArn" --output text
```

The seconds is to use jq if you wanted

```
aws elbv2 --region us-west-2 describe-rules \
    '--listener-arn=************'' \
    --output json | jq -r '.Rules[]|select(.RuleArn == "xyz")| .Actions[0].TargetGroupArn'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var res = JSON.parse(response);
```

To get the string in response to be parsed as Json.

Comment: :- How do i grab that string value for TargetGroupArn under "RuleArn": "xyz"

Answer (score 0):

To get the `TargetGroupArn` using `jq` you can use the following `filter`.

```sh
aws elbv2 \
  --region us-east-1 \
  describe-rules \
  --listener-arn="************" \
  | jq ".Rules[].Actions[].TargetGroupArn"
```

Another way would be to use the [`--query` option of the `aws cli`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter).